# Как из одной программы передать сообщение другой через WM_SETTEXT?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Подскажите, как с помощью WM_SETTEXT из одной программы передать сообщение другой, что бы в дальнейшей заголовок второй поменялся?

```
FindWindow(NULL, "Calculator");
LRESULT SendMessage(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"Заголовок-1");
HWND FindWindow(LPCTSTR lpClassName,
LPCTSTR lpWindowName
```

Comment: Рассмотрите вариант [FindWindow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) + [SetWindowText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtexta)

Comment: @acade FindWindow(NULL, "Calculator"); -  правильный ли это синтаксис?

Comment: В документации указано, что первый параметр может быть `NULL`, а второй является текстом заголовка окна. Так что - все в порядке.

Comment: @acade проблема в том,что при использовании именного этого кода "Calculator" подсвечивает красным

Comment: Вероятно, у вас включены широкоформатные символы и макрос `FindWindow` раскрывается в `FindWindowW` и требует вторым аргументом `const wchar_t*`. Попробуйте вызвать функцию отправив _широкую_ строку: `FindWindow(NULL, L"Calculator");`.

Comment: @acade спасибо, но так до конца и не понятно как работать с WM_SETTEX. Насколько я понимаю, сначала нужно использовать FindWindow, потом SendMessage в котором и используется WM_SETTEXT, не понятно как именно происходит процесс передачи сообщения и вместе с ним данных, в моем случае это изменить название второго окна, считав текущее

Comment: `FindWindow` нужен для того, чтобы получить дескриптор окна приложения. `SendMessage` отправит сообщение указанного типа (`WM_SETTEXT`) по полученному ранее дескриптору. Приложение, которому меняют текст обработает сообщение и выполнит все предусмотренные действия.